# How to configure BLE Wifi Sniffer and Node Red on Synology

Tags: mqtt, node-red, synology

I've bought a Wireless IBeacon Receiver BLE 4.0 WI-FI Sniffer [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-arrival-Wireless-iBeacon-Receiver/32463483551.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.1.E5Nlpv&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10151_10065_10344_10068_10342_10343_10059_10340_10314_10341_10534_100031_10084_10604_10083_10103_10304_10307_10615_10301_10142-10152_10151,searchweb201603_25,ppcSwitch_7&algo_expid=4b4879e7-ae62-4317-900d-c62510a648f9-0&algo_pvid=4b4879e7-ae62-4317-900d-c62510a648f9&priceBeautifyAB=0) installed Node Red on my Synology DS414j. I've been able to configure the sniffer to use my local WLAN and I can access the webpages on the sniffer. So far so good.

Now I'm trying to connect MQTT node from Node Red to the device. Maybe I'm not understanding thing correctly but I would have expected this to work.

There is a Wiki [here](http://wiki.aprbrother.com/wiki/Wireless_iBeacon_Receiver/en#How_to_Config) but that does not contain a lot of information. I tried signing on the forum but the confirmation mails never arrives.

Configuration of the sniffer:

1. I've added my SSID, security token for my WLAN. That works.
2. Device mode is configured to 'Station'
3. MQTT is configured to the IP of the NAS port 1883. With credentials. Topic is set to '/beacons'.
4. Node Red node is configured to IP of device port 1883, with credentials.

Questions:

1. Does it work the way I think this should work. Is it possible to have the MQTT Node Red node to connect to the device or do I need something else?
2. The sniffer can be put into 3 modes. Station, P2P and Access Point. I've now configured it at Station. Does anyone know what this setting means?
3. Node Red says 'connecting' but never connects. I've also installed a MQTT Dashboard on my Samsung Phone. It says 'connection failed'. What am I doing wrong? Do I need SSL/TLS? to be activated?

Comment: You have installed a MQTT broker on the NAS?

Comment: No, do I need one?

Comment: There is talk about Mosquito on the web. Is that what I need?

Comment: Which broker you choose is up to you, but yes you need one and yes mosquitto is one

Comment: Ah, ok, one more install to go :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Ok, installed Mosquitto. Had some trouble starting it but it runs now. Node Red connects to localhost without problems but nothing is received at the node. In the MQTT configuration I can add a User/PW. I've tried without, does not work. What is the PW for user 'Mosquitto'?

Comment: Ok, found the problem. I entered the DNS name as the server. After changing that to it's IP address it started working. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

By the sound of things you have not installed a MQTT broker.

MQTT is not Point to Point you need a broker that the clients all connect to.

Node-RED does NOT contain a MQTT broker (there is node to add one, but it's not really the best approach), it is just another MQTT client.